# Se produjo una excepción. SocketException (SocketException: OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111, address = localhost, port = 32830) en flutter

Tags: http, flutter, dart

Hola estoy tratando de conectar mi app flutter a una api rest que hice en nodejs, pero al hacer la peticion http aparece esto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el código que tengo en el método getUsers es este

```
Future<void> getUsers() async {
    final String url = 'http://localhost:3000/api/users';
    http.Response response = await http.get(url);
    print(response.body);
  }
```

probé cambiando el localhost por 10.0.2.2:3000, pero es una solucion que aparentemente sirve en emuladores virtuales, pero yo me encuentro depurando mi proyecto en mi dispositivo físico y no me funciona, me lanza el mismo error pero cambiando el localhost por el 10.0.2.2 o me congela la app.

¿Como puedo conectarme a mi api? el server lo tengo corriendo en el puerto 3000

Comment: solo usa la iP local y debería funcionar si están en la misma red

Comment: hola diego lo intente no me funciono, tanto el celular como el pc estaban conectado al mismo wifi  y hasta iguale la ip, puerto y dns de forma manual en el celular al pc y no funcionó

Comment: desde el celular entra al navegador,  puedes acceder a esa ip que mencionas? si no pues es un problema de conectividad, no tiene q ver mucho con flutter

Comment: gracias diego al final encontre otra solucion

Answer (score 1):

Bueno les mencionare las posibles soluciones que encontre que podrían resolverles el problema y al final la que yo utilicé:

1. Si te encuentras emulando tu proyecto en un virtualizador de Android studio sustituye el localhost por 10.0.2.2:#puerto.
2. Si lo estas emulando en dispositivo físico asegúrate de que estén en la misma conexión a Internet y cambia el localhost por 127.0.0.1:#puerto, si no funciona utiliza la ip local (puedes verla entrando al cmd y ejecutando ipconfig) 192.168.1.xx:#puerto (en las x van los ultimos numeros de tu ip)
3. si el punto dos no te funciono puedes probar creando una nueva regla de entrada y salida para el puerto en el que esté tu servidor (anexo: http://www.sf-technology.com/index.php/2017/08/24/reglas-de-entrada-y-salida-para-los-puertos-en-el-firewall-de-windows/), despues de haberlo hecho prueba de nuevo el punto dos.
4. si nada te ha funcionado a continuación te comento lo que me funcionó a mi... de antemano aclaro que no logré conectar mi dispositivo fisco al server del pc, lo hice mediante uno virtual (al estar dentro del mismo pc es más fácil conseguir esa conexión),

pero si como yo no cuentas con un pc de mas de 8 de ram para emular un virtual device de Android Studio, tener un server corriendo localmente, etc sin que el pc se quiera estallar, prueba descargando NoxPlayer (Sí ese mismo que usas para jugar freefire) configuralo para que tanto VSC y/o Android studio lo reconozcan y woala funciona, solo consumirá 160 megas de Ram (con mucha diferencia a la 1 Giga que consume uno de Android studio), en mi caso la conexion funcionó agregando la ip local y no el 10.0.2.2 que si funciona en uno de Android studio.

a continuacion las configuraciones que seguí

Habilitar Root y modo desarrollador en NoxPlayer

1. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4BKPyRoMvpE&t=196s
2. para que tanto VSC y Android studio reconozcan nox como un virtual device
   ingresa a tu sdk/platform-tools (en mi caso la ruta es asi C:\Users\"Nombre de usuario"\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools, recuerda que el AppData se encuentra como archivo oculto asi que tienes que activar la opcion "mostrar ocultos" en las opciones de vista del explorador de archivos) dentro de platfom-tools ingresa al cmd escribiendo cmd en la barra donde esta la ruta de la carpeta y presiona enter. ya dentro de cmd ejecuta el comando: adb connect 127.0.0.1:62001 y listo. Recuerda primero tener abierto tu editor de código y luego ejecutar el noxplayer para que lo reconozca.